# Did anybody ever go and look for extinct but sighted homo species on Flores and Papua New Guinea?

Tags: anthropology

Last month I read the book "Ich schwimme nicht mehr da, wo die Krokodile sind" ([link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/199857678-ich-schwimme-nicht-mehr-da-wo-die-krokodile-sind)). A wonderful book written by Sabine Kuegler, the Author of Jungle Child ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_Child_(film))). She grew up among indigenous tribes in Papua New Guinea as a child of German missionaries, and then moved to Switzerland and Germany.

In the book, she reports many locals report stories of spotting "small human like creatures". What is remarkable is that many different disconnected groups give similar descriptions, and even university educated people report having seen these creatures. Nonetheless, she discards these stories as fairy tales for years.

In the book she visits areas that have had almost no contact with modern society, and westerners maybe never visited. Even other tribes that have been in contact with modern society stay away from this "nomansland".

On page 252 (German version) she tells of coming eye to eye with an "Umemu", a human like creature that looks like a crossing between a spider and a human.

Original (German)

> Direkt vor mir, im Schein des Feuers, stand ein kleines Wesen. Es war etwa so Gross wie ein dreijähriges Menschenkind. Seine Haut war dunkel, es war völlig nackt. Sein Rumpf war winzig, die Arme und Beine im Verhältnis dazu extrem lang. Die Füsse an den dürren Beinen waen nach aussen gedreht, die ebenfalls dünnen Arme reichten bis unter die Knie. Sein Körper erinnerte an eine Spinne. Die Haare hatten die Struktur von dicken Dreadlocks un waren noch länger als seine Arme. Sein Körper und sein Gesicht waren mit Schmutz bedeckt, die Haare mit Schlamm überzogen. Es hatte ein wunderschönes Gesciht, dessen Züge eine fast perfekte Symmetrie aufwiesen, nahezu elfenhaft. Doch seine Augen schockierten mich, sie waren die eines angsteinflössenden Tieres, wild, intensiv, gefährlich, schwarz. Wie angewurzelt stand dieses Wesen vor mir und starrte mich mit diesen Augen an, ich startte zurück

Translation:

> Directly in front of me, in the glow of the fire, stood a small being. It was about the size of a three-year-old human child. Its skin was dark, completely naked. Its torso was tiny, with arms and legs proportionally extremely long. The feet on the thin legs were turned outward, and the equally thin arms reached down to below the knees. Its body resembled that of a spider. The hair had the texture of thick dreadlocks and was even longer than its arms. Its body and face were covered with dirt, and the hair was coated with mud. It had a beautiful face, with features displaying an almost perfect symmetry, almost elven. Yet its eyes shocked me; they were those of a frightening creature, wild, intense, dangerous, black. This being stood before me as if rooted to the spot, staring at me with those eyes, and I stared back.

The hunters she was with also say they saw the creature. They call it an "Umemu", a "man-spider". Local folklore says that these were the original inhabitants of Papua New Guinea, until modern humans came.

Professor Gregory Forth lived on Flores for 30 years, and reports similar eye witness accounts. He writes Homo Floriensis might still be alive. ([link](https://www.downtoearth.org.in/interviews/science-technology/ape-men-of-flores-gregory-forth-talks-about-academia-s-bias-against-testimonies-of-local-people-83254))

Googling around, I couldn't find any more information. Has anybody ever asked Sabine Kuegler about this? Could it be that another hominid species is still alive? Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. What fascinates me is that it appears nobody has ever looked! Why are anthropologists not over this like bees on honey?

Comment: Same reason no one's ever seen bigfoot - if there was a breeding population of them out there, we'd have far better ways than looking for living specimens to spot them. Dead bodies, dung, or even by ear (primates, even the least social, are LOUD).

Comment: Voting to close as social sciences other than history.

Comment: Except that expeditions looking for Bigfoot and Nessie actually happened as far as I can tell. Same for unicorns. We've looked and couldn't find them.

In this case, we have eye witness accounts and we've never looked... If empirical observation is the basis of everything then this is wide open.

Comment: Doesn't the article by Professor Forth, you linked to, answer why no one has looked? _As for living species, academic scientists don’t go in search of new species. If someone finds one, scientists investigate it. Also, there are certain institutional barriers. Scientists are unlikely to win grants or funding based on testimonies of local people as this is not considered scientific evidence._

Comment: Yes. But from what I can tell, the scientific consensus is that "All other species of hominids have died out". Not: "There are unexplored territories where other hominid species have been spotted, but we just haven't found the money to go and look to make sure". Why is this? Could it be that this a case of groupthink? Like how financial analysts wouldn't believe the housing market could go down until 2008? It seems absurd to me. Is there anybody in Athropological academia that can confirm this?

Comment: StackExchange History is explicitly not for trying to advance conspiracy theories or debunk the accepted consensus in favor of alternate views. This is off-topic here.

Comment: Searching for Bigfoot, Nessie or El Dorado is not what is history about and not what is History.SE for, but the study of the (obviously failed) searches for Bigfoot, Nessie or El Dorado is history. The history of searches of small hominids in Flores is also history.